# I have a json response and my Ember model is not matching for it

Tags: json, ember.js, ember-data

My Json response is like this

```
   {
        "object": {
            "assignments": [
                {
                    "assignmentId": 14706368,
                    "sectionId": 0,
                    "assignmentType": "FILEATTACH",
                    "assignmentTitle": "file attachment A",
                    "assignmentStartDate": "01/01/1900",
                    "assignmentStartTime": "01:00AM",
                    "assignmentDueDate": "01/01/2100",
                    "assignmentDueTime": "01:00AM",
                    "isMarathonChain": "No",
                    "assignmentTimeLimit": 0,
                    "assignmentTimeRemaining": "0",
                    "marathonAssignmentStatus": "MARATHON_NOT_ASSOCIATED",
                    "showAssignmentAttemptsAndPasswordDetails": false,
                    "assignmentAttemptsTaken": 0,
                    "assignmentAttemptsAllowed": "1",
                    "showPasswordForm": false,
                    "isStartAssignment": true,
                    "isResumeAssignment": false,
                    "isSubmitAssignment": false,
                    "passwordRequired": false,
                    "isConvertToGeniusEnabled": false,
                    "draftNumber": 0,
                    "studentExceptionExistsForDueDate": false,
                    "isPastUploadDate": false,
                    "showMarathonPrerequisiteInfo": false
                }
            ],
            "sections": [
                {
                    "sectionId": 241409387,
                    "courseId": 241409386,
                    "sectionName": "Section01"
                }
            ],
            "courses": [
                {
                    "courseId": 241409386,
                    "courseName": "Tricon.Connect_01",
                    "showDiscipline": false
                }
            ],
            "users": [
                {
                    "userId": 1000321061,
                    "firstName": "Ragu �������&^&",
                    "lastName": "+#@)()XYZ �^^������",
                    "userType": "S"
                }
            ],
            "returnLMS": [
                {
                    "returnUrl": "bb"
                }
            ]
        }
    }

My data model is like this

var attr = DS.attr;
App.About = DS.Model.extend({
 object: DS.hasMany('object')
 });

App.Object = DS.Model.extend({
  assignments: DS.hasMany('assignments'),
  sections: DS.hasMany('sections'),
  courses: DS.hasMany('courses'),
  users:  DS.hasMany('users'),
  returnLMS: DS.hasMany('returnLMS')
});

App.Assignments = DS.Model.extend({
assignmentId: attr('number'),
sectionId:attr('number'),
assignmentType:attr('string'),
assignmentTitle:attr('string'),
assignmentStartDate:attr('string'),
assignmentStartTime:attr('string'),
assignmentDueDate:attr('string'),
assignmentDueTime:attr('string'),
isMarathonChain:attr('boolean'),
assignmentTimeLimit:attr('number'),
assignmentTimeRemaining:attr('number'),
marathonAssignmentStatus:attr('string'),
showAssignmentAttemptsAndPasswordDetails:attr('boolean'),
assignmentAttemptsTaken:attr('number'),
assignmentAttemptsAllowed:attr('number'),
showPasswordForm:attr('boolean'),
isStartAssignment:attr('boolean'),
isResumeAssignment:attr('boolean'),
isSubmitAssignment:attr('boolean'),
passwordRequired:attr('boolean'),
isConvertToGeniusEnabled:attr('boolean'),
draftNumber:attr('number'),
studentExceptionExistsForDueDate:attr('boolean'),
isPastUploadDate:attr('boolean'),
showMarathonPrerequisiteInfo:attr('boolean')
});

App.Sections = DS.Model.extend({
sectionId: attr('number'),
courseId: attr('number'),
sectionName: attr('string')

});

App.Courses = DS.Model.extend({
courseId: attr('number'),
courseName: attr('string'),
showDiscipline: attr('boolean')
});

App.Users = DS.Model.extend({
userId: attr('number'),
firstName: attr('string'),
lastName: attr('string'),
userType:attr('string')
});

App.ReturnLMS = DS.Model.extend({
returnUrl: attr('string')
});
```

In this App.About is my route name so I have created object inside this and rest of it as follows.
No i am getting my response from restadapter but somehow it is not matching it with my model format and my model object show empty.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [JSON conventions](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/connecting-to-an-http-server/#toc_json-conventions) Ember Data is expecting.

You can also input your models into a neat tool called the [ember-data-model-maker](http://andycrum.github.io/ember-data-model-maker/), and see what the server responses should be.

If you don't have control over your server responses, you'll need to extend `DS.RESTAdapter` to manipulate your JSON to get it into the form Ember Data expects.